# how to read html code from a website with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the following code, but I got the error

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var jqxhr = $.get("www.goalzz.com", function () {
        alert("success");
    })
        .done(function () {
        alert("second success");
    })
        .fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    })
        .always(function () {
        alert("finished");
    });
});
```

Do read the html code with jQuery is possible?

Comment: same origin policy, you cannot do that. Proxify it server side or stop stealing other people work

Comment: Are you interested in a simple solution with jquery + php? that would be possible...

Comment: @siluaty : No thanks, I just want to work with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on "not possible"...

The "[Same origin policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" apply: your only way of communicating with the contents of iframes that come from another [domain|subdomain|protocol|port] is through the [postMessage API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging), which of course requires the other part (the document inside the iframe) to listen to your messages.

Comment: `postMessage` is for cross-frame/window communication. You can't use it with XMLHttpRequest (for which there are other options).

Comment: Why Windows applications can read them?  using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(_src);
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
                return doc;
            }

Comment: @SunRise using windows application, the client is the webbrowser component